# Inputting both ints and str and storing them into two separate lists

Tags: c++

User inputs `int`s and `string`s and program stores them into two separate lists in C++.

I get an error on `if (isNum(input))` - invalid arguments; could not convert input from char to string.

```
#include <list>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

bool isNum(string s)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
        if (isdigit(s[i]) == false)
            return false;
    return true;
}

int main(int argv, char* argc[])
{
    int i;
    string str;
    list<int> l;
    list<string> s;
    char input;

    do {
        cin >> input;
        if (isNum(input))
        {
            i = input;
            l.push_front(i);
        }
        else
        {
            str = input;
            s.push_back(str);
        }

        l.push_back(i);
        s.push_back(str);

    } while (i != 0);

    l.sort();

    list<int>::const_iterator iter;
    for (iter = l.begin(); iter != l.end(); iter++)
        cout << (*iter) << endl;
}
```

Comment: The type of `input` is `char`, so it will get a single character from the input. That makes it simple to test whether it represents a number. No need for `isNum` -- just call `isdigit` directly, once. If you change it to be `std::string`, that will fix that error, but then `i = input` won't make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not that easy ... But I'd let the stream do the work of deciding if it's an `int` or a `string`:

```cpp
#include <list>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()  // no parameters required for our program
{
    std::list<std::string> strings;
    std::list<int> numbers;

    int num;
    do {
        std::string str;
        if (std::cin >> num) {  // try to read an integer if that fails, num will be 0
            numbers.push_front(num);
        }
        else if (std::cin.clear(), std::cin >> str) { // reset the streams flags because
            strings.push_front(str);                  // we only get here if trying to
            num = 42;  // no, don't exit              // extract an integer failed.
        }
    } while (std::cin && num != 0);  // as long as the stream is good and num not 0

    strings.sort();

    std::cout << "\nStrings:\n";
    for (auto const &s : strings)
        std::cout << s << '\n';
    std::cout.put('\n');

    numbers.sort();

    std::cout << "Numbers:\n";
    for (auto const &n : numbers)
        std::cout << n << '\n';
    std::cout.put('\n');
}
```

#### Sample Output:

```
foo
5
bar
3
aleph
2
aga
1
0

Strings:
aga
aleph
bar
foo

Numbers:
0
1
2
3
5
```

Just a few things about your code:

- Avoid `using namespace std;` because it spills out the entire namespace std into the global namespace.
- Declare your variables as close to where they're needed.
- Use range-based `for`-loops where possible. Easier to write, easier to read.